# Hadoop - execute a terminal, commands in mapreduce

Tags: java, hadoop, mapreduce

I want to execute hadoop delete command to delete the processed input file after execution of job.

Comment: Did you do try to search for it?

Comment: what is the location of your processed input file ? Is it in the HDFS ?

Comment: yes the file is in hdfs

Answer (score 1):

> hadoop fs -rm URI [URI …]
>
> Delete files specified as args. Only deletes non empty directory and
>   files. Refer to rmr for recursive deletes. Example:
>
> ```
> `hadoop fs -rm hdfs://nn.example.com/file /user/hadoop/emptydir`
> ```
>
> Exit Code:
>
> Returns 0 on success and -1 on error.

Refer this for more : [Hadoop Commands](http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r0.18.2/hdfs_shell.html#rm)